# Need both Celsius and Fahrenheit with WeatherKit

Tags: swiftui, rounding, temperature, weatherkit

I have a weather app that tells the temperature in Celsius and Fahrenheit at the same time.  I'd like to use WeatherKit, but I'm having trouble rounding Celsius down to no decimal places. I can do it with Fahrenheit with .formatted because I'm based in the US, but I can't round down Celsius at the same time. Is there an easy way to do that in SwiftUI? Or is it possible to manually set the locale for just a single property?

```
            if let weather{
                
                let celsiusWeather = weather.currentWeather.temperature.converted(to: .celsius).description
                
                
                VStack{
                    Text("New York")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Text("\(weather.currentWeather.temperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).formatted().description)")
                    Text(celsiusWeather)
                }
            }
        }
```

This current code comes up with it half there:

> New York
> 45°F
> 5.98°C

But I would like it simply be 6°C instead. I've tried string interpolation:

`let celsiusFormatted = String(format: "%.0f", celsiusWeather)`

and that just came up with 0, not even any of the temperature, so I'm not sure if because it's from WeatherKit that it can do that or not.

Any help would be great. Let me know if you need more code to help clarify.

Answer (score 4):

You can format the temperature using `MeasurementFormatter`. Remember to set `numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0` to round the number as required and `unitOptions = .providedUnit` to ensure the correct units are displayed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let temp: Measurement<UnitTemperature>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("New York")
                Text(temp, formatter: formatter)
                Text(temp.converted(to: .celsius), formatter: formatter)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var formatter: MeasurementFormatter {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.unitStyle = .medium
        formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        return formatter
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
let celsiusFormatted = String(format: "%.0f", celsiusWeather.value)
```

`celsiusWeather` appears to be a measurement not a `Double` the `value` of a measurement is a `Double`.

You can also include precision for a `Text`

```
Text(weather.currentWeather.temperature.converted(to: .celsius), format: .measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided,numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))))
```

Comment: @BenG94 I also added the formatter with `Text` you just have to specify `numberFormatStyle`

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm not sure that this displays the correct units for Celsius - I think it uses the temperature units for the current locale

Comment: @AshleyMills oh yes, I forgot the provided part I added it.